# Sending Email From Flutter App Using flutter_email_sender or mailer

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to Send mail from Flutter App using  `flutter_email_sender`

```
sendEmail(){
    final Email email = Email(
      subject: "Text",
      body: "${User.userEmail + User.userCategory}",
      recipients: ["${User.userEmail}"],
      isHTML: false,
    );
    FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
  }
```

But the above code is opening mail application which is not I am trying to do.

I'm trying to send the mail on button click directly without using this application.

I know there is package called [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer), can any one suggest how to implement this with my backend (php).

Comment: for backend you can use dart web , this package mailer support dart web backend

Comment: hi @oshin , my total project backend is php(mySql). Can i use dart web only for this Functionality. Thanks for reply 

Comment: yes you can do this please check https://pub.dev/packages/mailer they have mentioned dart web for server side implementation